# gmaps4rails infowindow appears distorted with zurb foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails, zurb-foundation

[image]

I am attaching the screenshot of the infowindow below.It appears distorted and the left side bar is also not coming properly.

Here is my gmaps4rails.css

```
.map_container {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
  width: 623px;
}

.gmaps4rails_map {
  width: 623px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem occurs because of re-sizing of the images. Here is the link which helped

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Google-Maps-with-Twitter-Bootstrap-or-Zurb-Foundation

Comment: I read it but never thought that the issue could be because of zurb foundation :)

Comment: In the doc can you please include that this solution works for zurb foundation as well

Comment: Wiki are meant to be collaborative, please edit it: you've all details!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and added the following to my css file and it fixed the concern perfectly

img { max-width: none; }

Comment: where did you put that in your CSS?